# Xero - Get contacts simple API call

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, xero-api

I'm new to Xero development. I'm trying to make a simple API call to get all contacts from my clien't account.

I don't have the login details (user name & password) for the clien't account but I do have the Xero code from client which they have given me the required permissions.

So, the information I have are:

> Xero Code: 447a225c95XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX359d
>   Xero Scope:
>   openid profile email accounting.contacts accounting.transactions
>   offline_access

I'm not quite sure how to access my clien't Xero account with above details. Tried the following in Postman but do do know which header parameters to pass.

[image]

How do I make the API call to get contacts with above details?

Comment: If you have a look on the Xero youtube channel there are some quite informative videos on how to connect up, what headers to send and so on. I've gone from "not a clue" to working OK now on OAuth2 based on one of them. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7DA_vntKKChsenzpL7QWPg/videos

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the Oauth1 consumer token mixed up on the OAuth2.0 endpoint. If you are developing something new I 100% recommend you to setup authorization with OAuth2.0.

Also since you are using postman I encourage you to checkout our tutorials explaining how to get that setup: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/tools/postman

Please note that in order to connect API access you will need to have the email / password login for the xero user account you want to authorize API access for. You should setup a Demo Company and test this yourself. Please don't request your clients username/password to get access.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/getting-started-guide